# Restarting IPython kernel after installing new package - Hydrogen vs Jupyter

Tags: ipython, jupyter, hydrogen

I'm used to working with IPython kernels in Jupyter. Whenever I need to install a new Python package I simply install it via pip in the corresponding virtual environment. The package is immediately available in any notebook running with the kernel.

I recently discovered Hydrogen plugin for Atom. It seems to me that Hydrogen does not make recently installed packages available until the IPython kernel is restarted.

Is this expected behavior or am I missing something? If so, I think it is a deal breaker. If I am developing a package, restarting the kernel every time I need to test would be simply too painful.